TSX file type mismatch and key prop does not exist error
I am trying to create a simple next.js application and trying to generate a table as follows:
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
const UserTable = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const users: User[] = await res.json();
  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Email</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <tr key={user.id}>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

I get this error on the key attribute of the table row from TypeScript:
Type '{ children: Element[]; key: number; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>, HTMLTableRowElement>'.
  Property 'key' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>, HTMLTableRowElement>'.

So the property both does not exist but also is not of that type? What.
What am I doing wrong? It seems to be rendering correctly on the website and the node terminal does not give any errors either.

It's telling you that the <tr> element does not accept a key property.

@Derek It does say that, but it also gives an error when I do not set it as React expects a key property, and I am 100% sure it indeed does have one.

Instead of creating an object, you should directly use JSX for rendering inside the .map() function:
<tbody>
  {users.map((user) => (
    <tr key={user.id}>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
      <td>{user.email}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>

